# changing UITableView position programatically with AutoLayout support

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, autolayout

I want to change position of `UITableview` position programmatically. I have added following code in `viewDidLoad`,`ViewWillAppear` callbacks, but position is not changing.

```
Table.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,320,200);
```

When I disable `Auto Layout` option in Storyboard, Table View's position is changing. But, I need to keep `Auto Layout` option to maintain support for different device type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use autolayout, and set constraints to your tableView's position & size.
Then, create `IBOutlet` instances of the type `NSLayoutConstraint`, and attach them to your constraints in the xib.

Then, in your code, set the values of the constraints to reset the table view position.

Sample code:

in your .h file:

```
@property IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableOriginX;
@property IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableOriginY;
@property IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableWidth;
@property IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableHeight;
```

Then, in your .m file where you want to alter your table's frame:

```
tableOriginX.constant = 0;
tableOriginY.constant = 100;
tableWidth.constant   = 320;
tableHeight.constant  = 200;
```